# Freezing website after firebase deploy once I want to redirect to subpage

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-hosting

I'm running into an bizarre issue, that I haven't faced yesterday with exactly the same code and settings.

**But what is actually occuring?**
As my user gets authenticated and clicks to any link than the website freezes and there is no movement forward. I can see only the desired subpage as I copy the URL and open it in another tab.

Below you will find the firebase.json and also how my routes look like.

`firebase.json`:

```
{
  "functions": [
    {
      "source": "functions",
      "codebase": "default",
      "ignore": [
        "node_modules",
        ".git",
        "firebase-debug.log",
        "firebase-debug.*.log"
      ],
      "predeploy": [
        "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  },
  "storage": {
    "rules": "storage.rules"
  }
}
```

`App.js` (routes):

```
BrowserRouter>
  {user && <Navbar user={user} />}
  {!user && <UnloggedNavbar />}
  {!user && <HamburgerMenuUnlogged />}
  {user && <NotificationViewer />}
  {warningVisibility && user && <Warning />}
  {user && <HamburgerMenu />}

  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />

    <Route path="/about-us" element={<AboutUs />} />

    <Route
      path="/login"
      element={(!user && <Login />) || (user && <Home />)}
    />
    <Route
      path="/sign-up"
      element={(!user && <SignUp />) || (user && <Home />)}
    />
    <Route
      path="/book/:id"
      element={(user && <Book />) || (!user && <SignUp />)}
    />

    <Route
      path="/author/:authorName"
      element={<AuthorProfile />}
    />

    <Route path="/edit-test/:testId" element={<EditTest />} />

    <Route
      path="/test/:testId"
      element={
        (user && <TestMainPage />) || (!user && <SignUp />)
      }
    />

    <Route
      path="/test/:testId/play/:startTime/:attemptId"
      element={
        (user && <TestStartedPage />) || (!user && <SignUp />)
      }
    />

    <Route
      path="/create/book"
      element={
        (user && <CreateBook />) || (!user && <SignUp />)
      }
    />

    <Route
      path="/create/club"
      element={
        (user && <CreateClub />) || (!user && <SignUp />)
      }
    />

    <Route
      path="/create/competition"
      element={
        (user && <CreateCompetition />) || (!user && <SignUp />)
      }
    />

    <Route
      path="/create/test"
      element={
        (user && <CreateTests />) || (!user && <SignUp />)
      }
    />

    <Route
      path="/profile/:id/*"
      element={(!user && <SignUp />) || (user && <Profile />)}
    />

    <Route
      path="/user/profile/:id/*"
      element={(!user && <SignUp />) || (user && <Profile />)}
    />

    <Route
      path="/edit-profile"
      element={
        (user && <EditProfile />) || (!user && <SignUp />)
      }
    />

    <Route
      path="/add-link"
      element={(!user && <SignUp />) || (user && <AddLink />)}
    />

    <Route
      path="/message-to/:chatId"
      element={
        (user && <MessagesHolder />) || (!user && <SignUp />)
      }
    />

    <Route
      path="/your-chats/*"
      element={(user && <YourChats />) || (!user && <SignUp />)}
    />

    <Route
      path="/forgot-password"
      element={<ForgotPassword />}
    />

    <Route
      path="/sign-in-with-phone"
      element={
        (!user && <SignInWithPhone />) || (user && <Home />)
      }
    />

    <Route
      path="/login-with-phone"
      element={
        (!user && <LogInWithPhone />) || (user && <Home />)
      }
    />

    <Route
      path="/paymentForm/:paymentId/:sessionId"
      element={
        (!user && <SignUp />) || (user && <PaymentForm />)
      }
    />

    <Route
      path="/search"
      element={
        (user && <SearchOption />) || (!user && <SignUp />)
      }
    />

    <Route
      path="/search/:id"
      element={(user && <SearchFor />) || (!user && <SignUp />)}
    />

    <Route
      path="/competitions"
      element={
        (user && <Competitions />) || (!user && <SignUp />)
      }
    />

    <Route
      path="/competition/:id"
      element={
        (user && <Competition />) || (!user && <SignUp />)
      }
    />

    <Route
      path="/competition/:id/overall"
      element={
        (user && <GeneralInfo />) || (!user && <SignUp />)
      }
    />

    <Route
      path="/tests"
      element={(user && <Tests />) || (!user && <SignUp />)}
    />

    <Route
      path="/readers-clubs"
      element={(user && <Clubs />) || (!user && <SignUp />)}
    />

    <Route
      path="/readers-clubs/:id"
      element={(user && <Club />) || (!user && <SignUp />)}
    />

    <Route
      path="/readers-clubs/:id/overall"
      element={
        (user && <OverallClub />) || (!user && <SignUp />)
      }
    />

    <Route
      path="/edit-competition/:id"
      element={
        (user && <EditCompetition />) || (!user && <SignUp />)
      }
    />

    <Route
      path="/edit-club/:id"
      element={(user && <EditClub />) || (!user && <SignUp />)}
    />

    <Route
      path="/books"
      element={(user && <Books />) || (!user && <SignUp />)}
    />

    <Route path="/contact" element={<ContactPage />} />
  </Routes>
```

I tried to remove all firebase files like `.firebaserc`, `firebase.json` etc., logout from firebase with `npx firebase logout`, login again and run `npx firebase init` command selecting all the resources needed to make my project work and I specially bewared to set SPA to yes, and it's still going tits up. So I'm open to share more resources, answer questions. As I said before EXACTLY the same code has been running yesterday, as I had deployed it.

Comment: Ok, i actually fixed it guys. The problem was that i've been running an useEffect in my navigation.